# Выбор и оптимизация СУБД

Tags: база-данных

Планируется высоконагруженный сервис, в котором будет много запросов типа SELECT с поиском по столбцу, не являющимся индексным. То есть, будет требоваться выборка по характерике, не являющейся основной. Какую базу данных стоит выбрать для наилучшей скорости? Хранилище ключ-значение типа Redis не подходит. Стоит обратить внимание на NoSQL решения вроде MongoDB или лучше смотреть в сторону классического MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, что такой столбец будет не один (т.к. иначе его просто можно было бы проиндексировать). Если запросы будут по одному или множеству заранее неизвестных столбцов - посмотрите еще в сторону [Elasticsearch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticsearch), он отлично подходит под такой случай. К примеру, множественные фильтры в каталоге товаров или выборка по множеству тегов - это задачи как раз для Elasticsearch.